# Uploading additional files for inference from local - Sagemaker deploy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I'm attempting to deploy a local tensorflow model to a sagemaker endpoint. I want to include custom inference code to transform the input data. Given the model is trained and already located in an S3 bucket, I can run the following, which correctly deploys the model to an endpoint:

```
tensorflow_model = Model(
        model_data=saved_model,
        entry_point='src/development/document_matcher/inference.py',
        source_dir ='./src/development/document_matcher',      
        role=role, 
        framework_version=tf_framework_version
        )
```

The inference file is working correctly; however, I also need the vocabulary for the model to transform the incoming data correctly. This is what I'm trying to upload with source_dir.

My Directory structure is as follows:

```
- src
 - development
  -document_matcher
   - inference.py
   - total_vocab.pkl
```

I need to have total_vocab.pkl accessible to my inference script when it runs. However, inference.py is unable to find it. Am I misunderstanding how sagemaker works?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [SageMaker TF container](https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/281a191032446e61d871dfecf293451e4ebabd2b/tensorflow/inference/docker/build_artifacts/sagemaker/serve.py#L33) your `total_vocab.pkl` should be in `/opt/ml/model/code`

If it is not, seeing that your inference.py file is running I suggest adding some print statements to list directories.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/model.html), 'If `source_dir` is specified, then `entry_point` must point to a file located at the root of `source_dir`'. Therefore, since your Model object already unzips the whole `document_matcher` in the same location as your model, you can simply put  `entry_point = inference.py`. And your `total_vocab.pkl` object will be available in your `inference.py` code.